# Mudar DIV via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Eu tenho uma div com uma classe e quando a tela fica em 770px eu tenho um código que altera essa classe. Gostaria de além de alterar o nome da classe mudar ela de posição, exibir ela em outra div, como eu poderia faze-lo por jQuery?

**Exemplo**

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    var largura = window.innerWidth;

    if (largura < 750) 
        document.getElementsByClassName('carrinho.desktop')[0].className = 'carrinho.mobile';
});
```

Então esse carrinho.mobile eu gostaria de colocar dentro de outra div, relocando ele de lugar

**Exemplo de mudança**

```
<div class="Onde a div está/Carrinho desktop">
   <div class="classe que altera com o pixel"></div>
</div>

<div class="Para onde eu quero que vá a div/Carrinho mobile">
   <div class="quando a classe alterar vir pra cá"></div>
</div>
```

Se alguém quiser saber como ficou:

```
$j(window).resize(function() {
    windowsize = $j(window).width();
if (windowsize <= 769) {
        $j('.carrinho-cheio-mobile').replaceWith($j('.mini-cart-content.dropdown-content.left-hand.skip-content.skip-content-.-style.block-cart.block').clone());;
    }
})
```

Comment: Não entendi, explique melhor, por favor.

Comment: Vou reformular a pergunta.

Comment: Vê se ficou melhor para entender

Comment: Pelo o que eu entendi você quer mudar a forma de uma div de acordo com determinada resolução. Mas você quer fazer isso criando ou removendo o elemento em si e não o css, acredito que um código css já resolva seu problema, para ajudar precisaria de mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `.replaceWith(novoConteudo)` do JQuery. `novoConteudo` pode ser um objeto `jQuery`, um `Element`, uma string ou um Array.

Por exemplo; no caso exemplificado, o código ficaria assim:

```
$('.quando-a-classe-alterar-vir-para-ca').replaceWith($('.classe-que-altera-com-o-pixel'));
```

Caso você queira manter o "carrinho do desktop" no lugar, passe um `.clone()` do elemento como parâmetro do `replaceWith()`:

```
$('.quando-a-classe-alterar-vir-pra-ca').replaceWith($('.classe-que-altera-com-o-pixel').clone());
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f6x3reqy/)

Comment: Esse replace adiciona o conteúdo dentro dele? Irei testar aqui.

Comment: Sim, o replace substitui completamente o elemento JQuery em que ele é chamado pelo presente no parâmetro, logo, também altera o conteúdo interno dele.

Comment: Usei o replace e nem precisei mais usar o código de alterar a classe, pois eu iria fazer isso para não ter de mexer na original, mas com o .clone, a original fica la sem problema nenhum, obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Seria isso?

```js
function resize(){
  if (largura < 750) {
       $('.carrinhoDesktop').attr('class', 'carrinhoMobile');
       var carrinho = $('.carrinhoMobile');
       $('.carrinhoMobile').remove();
       $('.mobile').append(carrinho);
  }else{
   if($('.carrinhoMobile').length != 0){
        $('.carrinhoMobile').attr('class', 'carrinhoDesktop');
        var carrinho = $('.carrinhoDesktop');
        $('.carrinhoDesktop').remove();
        $('.desktop').append(carrinho);
      } 
  }
}
var largura = window.innerWidth;

resize(largura);

window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
largura = window.innerWidth;
resize(largura);
});
```

```css
. {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
}
.carrinhoDesktop {
  display: block;
}
.desktop {
  height: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}
.mobile {
  height: 20px;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desktop">
  <div class="carrinhoDesktop">carrinho</div>
</div>

<div class="mobile">

</div>
```

Comment: É basicamente isso, em cima do que me mandou estou conseguindo fazer aqui.